# Some of my pictures and fonts are not loading after uploading to host

Tags: 7

I've just uploaded my website to my host.  There was a 500 Internal Server Error at first, I looked into my htaccess file and after a lot of struggling with it I commented this line: `Options +FollowSymLinks` and then it worked but still some of my pictures and fonts are not loading, also I have some errors in my pages like:

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in drupal_environment_initialize() (line 702 of /home/simamedi/public_html/includes/bootstrap.inc
```

and

```
Warning: ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in include_once() (line 290 of /home/simamedi/public_html/sites/default/settings.php
```

Sorry, I'm quite new with these things, there's a live version of my website at [www.simamedia.com](http://www.simamedia.com).

Comment: Uploading files to a webserver doesn't sound like a Drupal question for the Drupal Answers site, even if you uploaded Drupal files.  Perhaps this question is a candidate for migration to Stack Overflow?

Comment: In your server, `ini_set()` has been disabled. The question is not specific for Drupal, and off-topic as per [faq].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `ini_set` is disabled by your hosting provider.  There is a [thread](http://drupal.org/node/54152) on drupal.org that may help.

Seems like your best option is to contact your hosting provider directly and see if there's anything they can do for you.

[This](http://drupal.org/node/54152#comment-1157728) might help as well.

> I had the exact same problem, and by reading the posts here and
>   Googling around I found out that this error is caused by ini_set being
>   disabled by the hosting provider.
>
> Unless you have root access, you cannot edit the php.ini file
>   directly, but at least on my hosting the support gave me these
>   instructions to circumvent the problem:
>
> Create a "php.ini" file in your `public_html` directory and put one line
>   of code exactly:
>
> `disabled_functions =`